# How to Multi/Process Parallelize PySpin

Tags: flir, pyspin, spinnaker-cam

I have a couple FLIR cameras which have been synchronized that I am controlling with PySpin. The problem is I have found there is that my FPS drops to unacceptable levels when processing the data sequentially.

The two operations which impact performance the worst are image acquisition and saving converted images.

I'm interested in :
 1. Parallelizing image acquisition for each camera.
2. Parallelizing image saving and image acquisition.

Can this be done? I found the pyspin/FLIR documentation not great.

Comment: **Welcome to S/O** What FPS target do you have & what have you done before asking question on StackOverflow? S/O is, since ever, based on a MCVE-formulations, kindly re-read the S/O advice on how to best ask questions & prepare a REPRODUCIBLE ( i.e. working and running ) + MINIMAL ( i.e. not overly sized, if less big, yet still reproducible form & shape of the MCVE-code keeps demonstrating the issue ). Doing that, the knowledge sponsoring members of this great Community of Merit, can & will help to the best achievable goal ( not losing any ones' expensive time in doubts, guestimates or alike )